# frama-c jessie killed during VC generation

Tags: frama-c

I'm trying to apply frama-c/jessie on a module of a proprietary safety critical system from our customer. The function under analysis is pretty big (image 700 uncommented lines count) with a  lot of conditional statements as well as complex (&&, ||, etc).

I got this error message when I ran it on Ubuntu VM 64 bit machine.  It appears Error 137 is related to memory size, etc. But I'm not quite sure.

Any suggestion for how to approach this error is greatly appreciated.

[

```
formal_verification]$ frama-c -jessie  test.c
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I.  -dD test.c"
[jessie] Starting Jessie translation
[jessie] Producing Jessie files in subdir test.jessie
[jessie] File test.jessie/test.jc written.
[jessie] File test.jessie/test.cloc written.
[jessie] Calling Jessie tool in subdir tests.jessie
Generating Why function testFun
[jessie] Calling VCs generator.
gwhy-bin [...] why/test.why
Computation of VCs...
Killed
make: *** [test.stat] Error 137
```

Answer (score 1):

> with a lot of conditional statements as well as complex (&&, ||, etc).

You should use the so-called “fast WP” option when analyzing functions with lots of nested conditionals. Otherwise, the target does not even need to be very large to cause a blowup.

It happens to be the example in [Jessie's manual](http://krakatoa.lri.fr/jessie.html) for passing options to Why (it is really a Why option):

```
-jessie-why-opt=<s>
give an option to Why (e.g., -fast-wp)
```

You would therefore use `-jessie-why-opt=-fast-wp`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I tried with the -fast-wp on alt-ergo but got the following timeout :total   :   1
valid   :   0 (  0%)
invalid :   0 (  0%)
unknown :   0 (  0%)
timeout :   1 (100%)
failure :   0 (  0%)
total wallclock time : 10 h 49 m 57 sec
total CPU time       : 5 h 32 m 11 sec
valid VCs:
    average CPU time : -nan
    max CPU time     : 0.00
invalid VCs:
    average CPU time : -nan
    max CPU time     : 0.00
unknown VCs:
    average CPU time : -nan
    max CPU time     : 0.00

Comment: Is it possible at all to use Jessie on a function that has 600 uncommented lines with a lot of conditional statements? I always get timeout, unfortunately. May be there is a trick I am missing?